# Flutter can't find custom widget using find.byType() in widget tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

I can't find custom Widgets in a ListView of widgets, but basic Widgets like Tex

OK:

```
testWidgets('test ListView with Text', (tester) async {
   await tester.pumpWidget(
       MaterialApp(home: ListView(children: [Text(''), Text('')])));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(Text), findsNWidgets(2));
 });
```

Failure:

```
  testWidgets('test ListView with CustomTile', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(home: ListView(children: [CustomTile(), CustomTile()])));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(CustomTile), findsNWidgets(2));
  });
```

Error:

```
Expected: exactly 2 matching nodes in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "CustomTile" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but some were expected
```

The custom tile looks like this:

```
class CustomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTile({
    Key? key,
    this.label,
    this.value,
    this.labelStyle = LabelStyle.none,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String? label;
  final String? value;
  final LabelStyle labelStyle;

  Widget _buildLabelRow(BuildContext context, String? label) {
    return label == null
        ? const SizedBox()
        : Text(
            label,
            style: labelStyle.textStyle,
          );
  }

  Widget _buildValueRow(BuildContext context, String? value) {
    return value == null
        ? const SizedBox()
        : Text(
            value,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(
                  color: MyColors.fdColorDark1,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
          );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Grid.x2),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          _buildLabelRow(context, label),
          _buildValueRow(context, value),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why can't I find CustomTiles when I can find Text with the same code?

Comment: If you define a key and try to find it with byKey, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the types in the tree, then most likely you are trying to find a DTO file or model instead of the exact class that is added to the tree, you need to examine the tree that is being built.